# WPF TabControl How to change Tab on mouse up rather than mouse down?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

In the WPF TabControl the default behavior is to change the selected tab on mouse down.

In my application changing the tab sometimes resizes things, and at times the mouse up event will get called on a another user control because the tabcontrol moved.

If i can set the tab pages to switch only on mouse up rather than mouse down it would solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom TabItem like so:

```
public class MyTabItem : TabItem {

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Source == this || !this.IsSelected)
            return;

        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Source == this || !this.IsSelected)
            base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e); // OR just this.Focus(); OR this.IsSeleded = true;

        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the PreviewMouseDown event and set the Handled flag of the routed event to disable the mousedown, and then on MouseUp you can set IsSelected on the TabItem. This way you don't have to create custom control.

XAML

```
<TabItem Header="My Tab" MouseUp="TabItem_MouseUp" PreviewMouseDown="TabItem_PreviewMouseDown">
    <!--Content-->
</TabItem>
```

C#

```
private void TabItem_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TabItem tab && !tab.IsSelected)
        tab.IsSelected = true;
}//end private void TabItem_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)

private void TabItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TabItem tab && !tab.IsSelected)
        e.Handled = true;
}//end private void TabItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```